# What is the difference between using fetch() or fs/promises readFile()?

Tags: node.js, fetch-api

What is the difference between using fetch() and fs/promises readFile() to read a data.json file? Both methods are asynchronous and both return a promise. what is best practice?

Comment: One makes a network request, the other reads from the file system. So...do you want to make a network request or read from the file system?

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  After reading about fetch() I was confused because some examples on the web show a local file being used with fetch(‘./data.json’).  At first, I couldn’t understand how these examples were using a local file with fetch(). But now it’s my understanding that a local or remote server is needed to read a local file with fetch() but not with readFile(). So, I wanted to make sure I wasn’t missing something with fetch(‘url’) vs fetch(‘./local.json’) vs fs.readFile(‘./local.json’).